# Cannot install gcc on CentOs 6.6

Tags: linux, centos, compiling, yum, gcc

I cannot install gcc on centOs because it cannot find some files, this is the last part of the console when I execute the "yum install gcc*":

    `--> Processing Dependency: binutils-hppa64-linux-gnu >= 2.23 for package: gcc-hppa64-linux-gnu-4.7.2-2.aa.20121114svn.el6.1.i686
---> Package gcc-ia64-linux-gnu.i686 0:4.7.2-2.aa.20121114svn.el6.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: binutils-ia64-linux-gnu >= 2.23 for package: gcc-ia64-linux-gnu-4.7.2-2.aa.20121114svn.el6.1.i686
---> Package gcc-java.i686 0:4.4.7-11.el6 will be installed
http://mirrors.coreix.net/centos/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 -
 "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://centos.mirroring.pulsant.co.uk/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR
 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/mirror.centos.org/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYC
URL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.mhd.uk.as44574.net/mirror.centos.org/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14]
 PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/mirror.centos.org/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 1
4] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors-uk.go-parts.com/centos/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR
 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] P
YCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirror.synergyworks.co.uk/centos/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERR
OR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.melbourne.co.uk/sites/ftp.centos.org/centos/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [E
rrno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
http://mirrors.vooservers.com/centos/6.6/updates/i386/repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 
22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: failure: repodata/0433e65e37015feb8fd655bdfba7785145fd36885449aa672573ba028a0df2b3-filelists.sqlite.bz2 from updates: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.`


Does anybody have an idea how I can fix it?

Comment: Check your network connection to the Internet. That output looks like you can't get to the Internet from that machine.

Comment: I did 'yum install gcc' and it installed gcc, but now I am wondering why the procedure is different, I has done something of different and it worked, so what's the difference between gcc and gcc*?

Comment: `gcc*` includes all packages that start with the letters `gcc`, which includes cross-compilers for PA-RISC and Itanium.

Answer (score 3):

There is something wrong with your mirrorlist. The fact that you got a 404 must mean that your internet connection is fine (assuming your DNS is configured correctly)

GCC comes from the base repo, so check the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and look at the `[base]` entry.

For example on my CentOS 6.6 system I have:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Also check if you can `curl` the mirrorlist url. See if you get a list of URL's when running the following command:

`curl "http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os"`

Comment: Explanation is OK, although that is pretty much irrelevant for the problem. Was probably fixed by `yum clean all --enablerepo="*"` and fetching new metadata with the next operation. As long as you see `Trying other mirror` the failover still works.

The actual underlying problem and answer to the question was explained by the short comment http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/203388/cannot-install-gcc-on-centos-6-6#comment342456_203388